# Ubuntu 12.04 black boot screen and boot-repair failed

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, virtualbox

I cannot boot Ubuntu 12.04 after from a copy of my VirtualBox file.

I am getting a "GNU GRUB version 1.99-12ubuntu5" screen with these options:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-24-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-24-generic (recovery mode)
Previous Linux versions
Memory test (memtest 86+)
Memory test [...]
```

Choosing option 1 or 2 leads me directly to a black screen.

Trying to fix this, I started with an Ubuntu Live Cd and run boot-repair.

Unfortunately, boot-repair failed with this link.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7024127/

Now I am stuck.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VirtualBox. Here is a link that directly relates to your issue. I don't like posting links, but it's really not my fix, I found it here, so people, please be nice.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=55146

Hope this helps!